# Integrity constraint violation for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_PRODUCT_SUPER_ATTRIBUTE_PRODUCT_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID'

Tags: magento, configurable-product

I am creating simple products and then configurable product followed by associating simple products with configurable product. When I run the code for the first time, it works smoothly creating all simple products, configurable product and also an association. But, when I run that code again it says constraint violation. The ID that shows duplicated is the same product ID that was created the last time, when all process were ok.

My code is the following one.

```
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$toinsertId = $product_collection->getLastItem()->getId() + 1;

$configurable_attribute = "art_print_sizes";
$attr_id = 133;
$simpleProducts = array();
$lowestPrice = 999999;

$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/advanced')->getAttributes();
$attributeArray = array();
foreach ($attributes as $a) {
    if ($a->getAttributeCode() == 'art_print_sizes') {
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($a->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $option) {
            $option_id = $this->getOptionId("art_print_sizes", $option['label']);
            $sku = 'SK_' . '500' . '_' . strval($count);

            $sProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $sProduct
                ->setTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
                ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                ->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
                ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE)
                ->setTaxClassId(5)
                ->setAttributeSetId(9)
                ->setSku($sku)
                // $main_product_data is an array created as part of a wider foreach loop, which this code is inside of
                ->setName($wholedata['name'] . " - " . $option['label'])
                ->setShortDescription($wholedata['short_description'])
                ->setDescription($wholedata['description'])
                ->setPrice(sprintf("%0.2f", $wholedata['attr_val'][$count]))
                ->setData($configurable_attribute, $option_id);

            $sProduct->save();

            array_push(
                $simpleProducts,
                array(
                    "id" => $sProduct->getId(),
                    "price" => $sProduct->getPrice(),
                    "attr_code" => 'art_print_sizes',
                    "attr_id" => $attr_id,
                    "value" => $option_id,
                    "label" => $option['label']
                )
            );

            $count++;
        }
    }
}

$cProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$productData = array(
    'name' => 'Main configurable Tshirt',
    'sku' => 'tshirt_sku',
    'description' => 'Clear description about your Tshirt that explains its features',
    'short_description' => 'One liner',
    'weight' => 1,
    'status' => '1',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'attribute_set_id' => 9,
    'type_id' => 'configurable',
    'price' => 1200,
    'tax_class_id' => 0

);
foreach ($productData as $key => $value) {
    $cProduct->setData($key, $value);
}

$cProduct->setStockData(
    array(
        'manage_stock' => 1,
        'is_in_stock' => 1,
        'qty' => 0,
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0
    )
);

$cProductTypeInstance = $cProduct->getTypeInstance();
$attribute_ids = array(133);

$cProductTypeInstance->setUsedProductAttributeIds($attribute_ids);
$attributes_array = $cProductTypeInstance->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
foreach ($attributes_array as $key => $attribute_array) {
    $attributes_array[$key]['use_default'] = 1;
    $attributes_array[$key]['position'] = 0;

    if (isset($attribute_array['frontend_label'])) {
        $attributes_array[$key]['label'] = $attribute_array['frontend_label'];
    } else {
        $attributes_array[$key]['label'] = $attribute_array['attribute_code'];
    }
}

$cProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($attributes_array);

$dataArray = array();
foreach ($simpleProducts as $simpleArray) {
    $dataArray[$simpleArray['id']] = array();
    foreach ($attributes_array as $key => $attrArray) {
        array_push(
            $dataArray[$simpleArray['id']],
            array(
                "attribute_id" => $simpleArray['attr_id'][$key],
                "label" => $simpleArray['label'][$key],
                "is_percent" => 0,
                "pricing_value" => $simpleArray['pricing_value'][$key]
            )
        );
    }
}
$cProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($dataArray);
$cProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
$cProduct->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$cProduct->save();
```

The Error is like this

[image]

Product ID 126 is already added in database in previous session. And previous session went well adding all necessary products.

[image]

Comment: Please check this link it may be helpful. http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/m/viewthread/272000/

Comment: I see webkul is running, try to disable webkul_marketplace and try again. If success, ask webkul to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Magento will not allow you to update configurable products. So for resolve it just add below code

```
if($productId){
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_super_attribute');
    $write->delete($table,"product_id = " . $productId);
}
```

before

```
$cProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($attributes_array);
```

So your final code will be

```
if($productId){
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $table = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_super_attribute');
    $write->delete($table,"product_id = " . $productId);
}
$cProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($attributes_array);
```

**Note: Change $productId variable according to your code. You have to pass product id here.**